# validate.js returning error "unknown validator pattern"

Tags: node.js, validation, validate.js

I'm trying to use validate.js to validate input from the front end before entering it in the database with node but I'm getting an error that I can't figure out. I've gone over the docs and believe I setup the constraints correctly. The exact error is:

```
message:"Unknown validator pattern"
```

my validator is setup like this:

```
                    let alphanumeric = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/;
                    let constraints = {
                        clientUsername:{
                            presence: true,
                            length: {min:8, max:15},
                            pattern:alphanumeric,
                            message: 'make sure client username is between 8-15 characters, is only numbers and letters'
                        },
                        tileCategory:{
                            presence:true,
                            length:{min:1, max:1},
                            numericality:{
                                onlyInteger:true,
                                lessThanOrEqualTo:tileCategoryNumber,
                            },
                            message:'enter a number, 1 char in length, less than or equal to 3' //the current number of tiles
                        }
                    };

                    validate({clientUsername: input.clientUsername},constraints);
```

At first I thought it was the regex pattern but  tried commenting that out and then it said

```
message:"Unknown validator messsage"
```

so I'm guessing there is something wrong with my validator in general.

at the very top I of course included `const validate = require('validate.js');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something similar to this just burned me, have a look at [the documentation](https://validatejs.org/#validators-format) again.

`pattern` is sort of a sub-validator of `format` and should look like:

```
{
    format: {
        pattern: "[A-Za-z0-9]+"
    }
}
```

You're trying to use `pattern` at the "top level". I don't see anything in the documentation that implies helper patterns like `alphanumeric` exist. (I think the language the tool would use is to say "`pattern` is an option of the `format` validator" but I'm not sure.)

Your stated error message also implies a misspelling: it tells you it doesn't recognize `messsage`, which has 3 of the letter 's' but should have 2.

Answer (score 1):

There's (2) things I could see being the issue. Firstly, you're using JS based regexes with the preceding and following /. Try removing these.

Beyond that, I'd recommend trying to remove the alphanumeric parameter & input the regex directly... it may be a type issue as well.

```
  pattern:"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$",
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: given the error that was the first thing I tried. It still doesn't work though. Thanks for trying to help.